# PHP: How does this statement work

Tags: php

How does this statement get evaluated to produce `234`.

```
echo '3'.(print'2')+3; // output 234.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the echo command to display a string. This string is a concatenation of a string "3" and the result of the call to print '2' added with the number 3.

During the concatenation print '2' is evaluated, thus the output starts with that. Afterwards the concatenated string '34' is printed, where the 4 is the result of 1 (=true, the result of the print call) + 3

Way too much text, but I hope that covers it all.